# Local DateTime Parsing 2023-02-22T09:47:00.5371934+03:00 and 2023-02-22T09:47:00.537

Tags: java, spring, xml-parsing, wsdl, isodate

How can I parse this code to localDateTime?

I have 2 area that give me localDateTime, One of them is 2023-02-22T09:47:00.5371934+03:00 the other one is 2023-02-22T09:47:00.537 and response like this:

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-02-22T09:47:00.537' could not be parsed at index 23 \n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:195)

I have tried DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME, it didn't work.

Do u you have any suggestions?

Comment: share your code

Comment: These are different formats. One is a `ZonedDateTime`, the other is a `LocalDateTime`. You need to parse them using different formats.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should hardly want to process any of those as `LocalDateTime`. If you know from which 2 areas they come, then the `ZonedDateTime` class that @f1sh refers to is probably right, but will require a (different) conversion for each. So for starters, from which two areas do they come?

Comment: yes, I tried different conversion for each areas and the problem is solved thank you  @f1sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your first input has an offset of three hours ahead of UTC. So parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2023-02-22T09:47:00.5371934+03:00" ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

This other input has no offset, and no time zone. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2023-02-22T09:47:00.537" ) ;
```